# Renaming expressions dynamically in Mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I am trying to write a statement that will create a new positionVector as I parse through a matrix.

What I am trying to accomplish would look something like this,

For[i = 1, i <= vectorlength, i++ positionVector "i" = positionVector[[i]]

Where the position vectors for every "i" are reassigned to positionVector1, positionVector2, etc.

Forgive me if I used the wrong terminology, as I am relatively new to Mathematica.

Cheers,
John

Comment: Curious. If you can reference the vector as `positionVector[[i]]` why  do you need to create variables named positionVecotor<n> ?

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: You may create a new symbol by: Symbol["positionVector"<>ToString[i ]]. But, as Edmund noted, what for do you need this?

Comment: @Edmund This was a very specific question, with general application (on my part) that I have been pondering for a little while and this was relevant for the formulation of the code at this time. For the method that I am building the code for, Kane's Method for a spring, I am building a program that can handle different discretizations of the parameters. Downstream, I need to have a way to treat the "nodes" inidividually without having to manually update this section of the code. If I access the vector 'positionVector[[i]]' I think I would have to do this manually.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to create variables (that are named *postionVector1* to *postitionVector****N***, where ***N*** is the length of a list) and assign a value for each item in the *positionVector* list. `Symbol` creates the variable names, and `MapThread` assigns values.

```
Remove["positionVector@*"]
MapThread[
 Function[{h, v}, h = v], 
   {Symbol["positionVector" <> ToString@#] & /@ 
     Range[Length[positionVector]],
    positionVector}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the (undocumented) built-in function `` Statistics`Library`GenerateUniqueVariables ``:

```
Statistics`Library`GenerateUniqueVariables["positionVector", 4, {}]
```

> ```
> {positionVector1, positionVector2, positionVector3, positionVector4}
> ```

The first argument may be a symbol:

```
Statistics`Library`GenerateUniqueVariables[positionVector, 4, {}]
```

> ```
> {positionVector1, positionVector2, positionVector3, positionVector4}
> ```

```
Statistics`Library`GenerateUniqueVariables[foo, 10, {}]
```

> ```
> {foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4, foo5, foo6, foo7, foo8, foo9, foo10}
> ```

The third argument is used as the *blacklist* of symbols to be skipped:

```
Statistics`Library`GenerateUniqueVariables[foo, 8, {foo5, foo9}]
```

> ```
> {foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4, foo6, foo7, foo8, foo10}
> ```